# htop: Open with processes hidden

Tags: htop

On large machines with a lot of CPU cores, the process list hides the CPUs. I want to open htop without the process list by using CLI arguments and/or env vars.

I do not want to alter a global config files, as I also want to have another htop instance open that has the process list.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in the post
[How to monitor system resource usage without showing process list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421703/how-to-monitor-system-resource-usage-without-showing-process-list).

I quote below the answer by Terrance.

> I am not aware of a way to not show the processes in `htop`, but if
> you go with a similar alternative like `btop` or `bpytop` you can turn
> off the showing of the processes by pressing <kbd>4</kbd> on the
> keyboard.
>
> Examples:
>
> **BTOP:**  To install `btop` it is `sudo snap install btop`.  Then to run it just `btop` from a terminal window.
>
> *`btop` with processes:*
>
> [image]
>
> *`btop` without processes:*
>
> [image]
>
> **BPYTOP:** To install `bpytop` it is `pip3 install bpytop`.  Then to run it just `bpytop` from a terminal window.
>
> *`bpytop` with processes:*
>
> [image]
>
> *`bpytop` without processes:*
>
> [image]

Comment: How to open these with only CPU cores shown? There is still a lot of extra stuff in these screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The [man page for `htop`](https://manpages.org/htop) mentions a `--pid` option to only show specific processes. Using: `htop -p 0` works fine for me. Empty process list (but header still visible).

<sup>And since your primary goal is to shorten the process list you could also use `htop -p 1` if 0 does not work to only show one process.</sup>

Comment: This still fills the space used for processes with blank. So it doesn't actually free up the space.